# Optimizing algorithm calculating (sin(x)-x)*x^{-3} (in matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, numerical-methods

My task is to write optimal program that calculates matrix `Y`, given matrix `X`, where:

y = (sin(x)-x) x<sup>-3</sup>

Here's the code I have written so far:

```
n = size(X, 1);
m = size(X, 2);
Y = zeros(n, m);
d = n*m; 

for i = 1:d
    x = X(i);
    if abs(x)<0.1
        Y(i) = -1/6+x.^2/120-x.^4/5040+x.^6/362880;
    else
        Y(i) = (sin(x)-x).*(x.^(-3));
    end
end
```

So, generally the formula was inaccurate around 0, so I have approximated it using Taylor theorem.

Unfortunately this program has accuracy of 91% and efficiency of only 24% (so it's 4 times slower than the optimal solution).

The tests are around 13 million samples, out of which around 6 million have value of less than 0.1. The range of samples is (-8π , 8π).

The target accuracy (100%) is `4*epsilon` where `epsilon` equals `2^(-52)` (that means that numbers calculated by program shouldn't be larger or smaller than numbers calculated "perfectly" than `4*epsilon`).

`100*epsilon` means accuracy of 86%.

***Do you have any ideas on how to make it faster and more accurate?*** I'm looking both for mathematical tricks on how to further transform given formula, and general MATLAB tips that can accelerate programs?

EDIT:
Using Horner method, I have managed to bring up efficiency up to 81% (accuracy still 91%) with this program:

```
function Y = main(X)

Y = (sin(X)-X).*(X.^(-3));
i = abs(X) < 0.1;
Y(i) = horner(X(i));

function y = horner (x)

pow = x.*x;
y = -1/6+pow.*(1/120+pow.*(-1/5040+pow./362880));
```

Do you have any further ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What do you meanby optimizing algorithm? Do you want to find the optimal (minimal/maximum value) of the function, as in [fminsearch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html)? Or you want to calculate the value of the function? In that case, the for-loop is unecessary. The statement: `Y = (sin(X)-X)./X^3` should work for the entire array, without the necessity to iterate through every member of the array.

Comment: @Thales by optimizing I meant to make it faster and more accurate. Calculating simply Y = (sin(X)-X)./X^3 is wrong, because the accuracy would be higly lowered around 0 (and half of the samples are going to be near 0)

Comment: Could you give a numerical example of what you are asking? What is the expected range for the `x` variable? When it fails to accurately calculate?

Comment: what you mean by 'Unfortunately this program has accuracy of 91% and efficiency of only 24% (so it's 4 times slower than the optimal solution).'

Comment: @Thales what do you mean "numerical example"? I am supposed to calculate the given formula as fast and as precisely as possible. That's all.

Comment: @Thales my proffessor gave us program (precompiled - we can't see the code) that is supposed to be "perfect solution". The values of accuraccy and efficancy are in comparsion to that program.

Comment: I added an answer about the questions I asked. you have a function that is difficult to accurately calculate in a digital computer due to round-off errors and the [arithmetic of floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). you have a taylor series expansion valid for the vicinity of the point x=0, which is a good approximation. You can either use the function or its aproximation. What else you want to calculate?

Comment: @CrisLuengo why would I? I only need it when the outcome of substraction sin(x)-x is close to 0, not when sin(x) is close to 0

Comment: @Thales yes I know. My program is 4 times slower than it should be. Making it faster is the main reason of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your loop with vectorized code. This is usually more efficient than loop because the loop has a conditional in it, which is bad for [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array):

```matlab
Y = (sin(X)-X).*(X.^(-3));
i = abs(X) < 0.1;
Y(i) = -1/6+X(i).^2/120-X(i).^4/5040+X(i).^6/362880;
```

Rewriting the primary equation to avoid the cubic root yields a 3x speedup for that computation:

```matlab
Y = (sin(X)./X - 1) ./ (X.*X);
```

---

**Speed comparison:**

The following script compares timing for this method compared to OP's loop code. I use data that has 7 million values uniformly distributed in (-8π, 8π), and another 6 million values uniformly distributed in (-0.1,0.1).

OP's loop code takes 2.4412 s, and the vectorized solution takes 0.7224 s. Using OP's Horner method and the rewritten `sin` expression it takes 0.1437 s.

```matlab
X = [linspace(-8*pi,8*pi,7e6), linspace(-0.1,0.1,6e6)];
timeit(@()method1(X))
timeit(@()method2(X))

function Y = method1(X)
n = size(X, 1);
m = size(X, 2);
Y = zeros(n, m);
d = n*m; 

for i = 1:d
    x = X(i);
    if abs(x)<0.1
        Y(i) = -1/6+x.^2/120-x.^4/5040+x.^6/362880;
    else
        Y(i) = (sin(x)-x).*(x.^(-3));
    end
end
end

function Y = method2(X)
Y = (sin(X)-X).*(X.^(-3));
i = abs(X) < 0.1;
Y(i) = -1/6+X(i).^2/120-X(i).^4/5040+X(i).^6/362880;
end

function Y = method3(X)
Y = (sin(X)./X - 1) ./ (X.*X);
i = abs(X) < 0.1;
Y(i) = horner(X(i));
end

function y = horner (x)
pow = x.*x;
y = -1/6+pow.*(1/120+pow.*(-1/5040+pow./362880));
end
```

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, almost half of the samples are near 0, so your answer is invalid

Comment: as I commented above, reducing Taylor range usage gave me only small boost to efficency, but a major lose to accuracy. By trials and errors I found the number 0.1 to work best.

Comment: ok it appears that indeed it works faster, but it's still only 40% (so more than 2 times slower than the model program). The accuracy obviously is still 91%

Comment: decrasing the range of Taylor series usage rises the speed only slightly, while greatly reducing accuracy

Comment: it's still more than two times slower than it should be. Can you think of other ways of improving the speed? I think that maybe it's possible to transform the formula so that it is calculated quicker?

Comment: oh I think calculating the Taylor expansion using Horner method should be faster.

Comment: I have edited my question, adding what I have achieved using Horner method. Do you have any further insights?

Comment: @MartinYakuza: Were you told to reproduce the speed and accuracy of the compiled program in MATLAB, or is MATLAB your own choice? I think getting to 80% of the speed of a compiled program is pretty good. I C and C++ you also have access to `long double`  format (10-bytes), which you can use to improve accuracy significantly. The only thing I can think of to further improve the speed of computation is not to compute the `sin` version for `~i`: `j=~i; Y(j) = (sin(X(j)-X(j)).*(X(j).^(-3));`. And not using the division, for example replacing `./362880` by `.*2.755731922398589e-06`.

Comment: @MartinYakuza: Rewriting the `sin` expression gives another good speed advantage (see edited answer). The ideas in my previous comment didn't.

Comment: yes rewriting sin expression raised efficency up to 130%! But unfortunately it slighly decrases the accuracy - it is 88%, which is too low (my program need to have at least 90% accuracy to be accepted)

Answer (score 2):

Program seems to work fine for a great range of input:

```
x = linspace(-8*pi,8*pi,13e6); % 13 million samples in the desired range
y = (sin(x)-x)./x.^3;
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Due due [round-off errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error), you may have problem calculating it for very small values of x:

```
x = 0
y = (sin(x)-x)./x.^3
```

> ```
> y =
>
>    NaN
> ```

You already have the Taylor series expansion of the function around 0. As the Taylor expansion does not include a division by `x`, you can expect a better behaviour of the Taylor function around this region:

```
x = -1e-6:1e-9:1e-6;
y = (sin(x)-x)./x.^3;
y_taylor = -1/6 + x.^2/120 - x.^4/5040 + x.^6/362880;
plot(x,y,x,y_taylor); legend('y','taylor expansion','location','best')
```

[image]

Comment: sooo - you have just drawn what I have been talking about? That doesn't answer my question at all. I need to make my program faster.

Comment: Did you checked my code? It has no for loops. It runs faster.

Comment: you can't calculate all samples with Taylor expansion - it is accurate only for numbers around 0, but it's inaccurate for larger numbers.

Comment: @MartinYakuza: This answer seems to indicate that you should only use the Taylor expansion when you're within 0.5e-6 of 0, not within 0.1. Where does your 0.1 cutoff come from?

Comment: @Thales using your range I get efficency of 28% (slightly higher), but accuracy of only 26% (much, much lower). I got number 0.1 by trials and errors - it gave me best accruacy and efficency combination.